# Passing parameters stored in a variable to bat file from excel macro

Tags: excel, vba

I have a scenario where two arguments which may contain white space need to be passed to a bat file during runtime via macro script.

*bat file script:*

```
echo %1
echo %2
```

*Vba:*

```
Sub Button1_Click()
    Dim oShell As Object
    Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")    
    Dim oExec As Object
    Dim oOutput As Object
    Dim arg1 As String: arg1 = "New Folder"
    Dim arg2 As String: arg2 = "My Activity"
    Set oExec = oShell.Exec("G:\Sample\test.bat" & " " & arg1 & " " & arg2)
    Set oOutput = oExec.StdOut

    'handle the results as they are written to and read from the StdOut object
    Dim s As String
    Dim sLine As String
    While Not oOutput.AtEndOfStream
        sLine = oOutput.ReadLine
        If sLine <> "" Then MsgBox sLine
    Wend
End Sub
```

The above code gives output as follows:

```
New
Folder
```

but expected output is:

```
New Folder
My Activity
```

Kindly help me in resolving this issue as am new to macro

Answer (score 2):

Arguments which may have spaces should be quoted

```vb
Set oExec = oShell.Exec("G:\Sample\test.bat" & " """ & arg1 & """ """ & arg2 & """")
```

Comment: Yes, of course +:)

Comment: Thanks! this helps. But the output contains quotes so this causes problem when tried to pass the 'arg1' as part of a long path which in turn is passed as command line argument to 'javac' command. eg:) Suppose 'arg1 = "New Folder"' set in vba is passed to batch file which has following 'java "D:/Sample code/"%1 filename'. which is displayed as "D:/Sample code/""New Folder" and java compilation is failing. Kindly help me in resolving this issue.

Comment: That sounds like you need a new question

Comment: Why pass parameters to a bat file only to pass them on again to javac?  Why not skip the bat file?

Comment: Bat file contains the java command to compile java file and associates jars and folders in class path. The args are the java file names passed from macro dynamically

Answer (score 0):

What about simply using a temporary placeholder as WScript doesn't seem to accept non-breaking space (`Chr(160)`) instead of simple space?

```
Sub EchoBatTest()
    Const tmp As String = "$!$"                        ' << define any temporary placeholder
    Dim oShell As Object
    Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    Dim oExec As Object
    Dim oOutput As Object
    Dim arg1 As String: arg1 = "New" & tmp & "Folder"  ' << insert tmp
    Dim arg2 As String: arg2 = "My" & tmp & "Activity"
    Set oExec = oShell.Exec("C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Stack\txt\EchoTest.bat" & " " & arg1 & " " & arg2)
    Set oOutput = oExec.StdOut

    'handle the results as they are written to and read from the StdOut object
    Dim s As String
    Dim sLine As String
    While Not oOutput.AtEndOfStream
        sLine = Replace(oOutput.ReadLine, tmp, " ")    ' << re-insert space(s)
        If sLine <> "" Then MsgBox sLine
    Wend
End Sub
```